# Hive query failing - can't determine table schema

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, avro

All Hive queries to a table are failing with the following reason:

> java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerdeException: Neither
>   avro.schema.literal nor avro.schema.url specified, can't determine
>   table schema

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem has been reported in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3953 and fixed in Hive 0.14. Upgrading Hive to the most recent version solved the issue.